# How to create block frames in Oracle Forms 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

When you create a new block in an Oracle form using the block wizard, by default it draws a frame around it, with the block's name or description in the frame.

Does anybody know how to create a frame on a block that already exists?  The only thing I've come up with so far is to copy an existing frame, and then relocate, resize and rename it to meet my current needs.  It would be nice if I could just create one.

Thanks,
AndyDan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Frame tool on the Tool Palette (which you can display in the Layout Editor by checking the Tool Palette item on View menu).  You can use this to draw a new frame.  Using the Property Palette, you can then set the Layout Data Block property of the frame (in the Layout Frame group) to the name of the block you want to display in the frame.  You can set the other properties of the frame in the Layout Frame group to control how items in the block are laid out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I need!  I never saw it there before, perhaps because I expected it to be nearer (and look more like) the rectangle button.  To me, at least, the icon on the button looks more like a little clipboard than a frame, but now that I know what it is, it makes sense.